# c# WinForm how to retrieve value from resource file on code behind

Tags: c#, winforms, localization, resources

In asp.net I use like this:

```
  gridView_Desti.Columns["CODE_DEST"].Caption = (string) HttpContext.GetGlobalResourceObject("Client", "Code_Dest");
```

How can I do the same thing on WinForm ?

Client is the resource name file --> Client.resx 
Code_Dest is string on Client.resx --> string Code_Dest, value Code Destinataire

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do :

```
Client.ResourceManager.GetString("Code_Dest");
```

Depending on the culture, it will look for the string in Client.en-US.resx (if en-US is your current culture) and if it fail, in Client.resx.

You can also acces like this (Code_Dest must be in Client.resx) :

```
Client.Code_Dest;
```

Answer (score 3):

You should have an auto-generated class called `Resources` in the `Properties` namespace of your project. Each resource is exposed as a property in that class.

Answer (score 0):

1. Add new item -> Resources i.e 'Resources1.resx'

   1. Put necessary Resources Name & value ie string resources -> 'YourResourcesName' value whatever.
   2. Access its value with `Resources1.YourResourcesName`

Hope this help,

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have the namespace in, then prepend with "Properties" C# as so:

```
Properties.Resources1.YourResourcesName
```

Makes your code so much cleaner using the resx file.  As an example, I have a DataGridViewImageColumn and assigned an image to it (from VS Image Library - the image is a .png file):

```
colAddNewItem.Image = Properties.Resource1.Add_16x;
```

FYI, in VB.Net it's

```
Resources.Resources1.YourResourcesName
```

There are many other ways, but this is the simplest, cleanest & preferred method.